# Program to fit text into a fixed size box

Tags: desktop-publishing

I need a program that can take in:

- a chunk of text
- the dimensions of a box the text needs to fit inside

...and then output an image with the dimensions of the box provided, and the text laid out inside.

### Longer version / Why?

This image will then be fed into an imagemagick script that will place it on a game card.

At this point, I've automated every part of the process; All the cards in the deck are automatically built from the text I feed into the program. The individual card images are then put together onto a single sheet, ready for printing and die cutting. All this happens in a single command-click. The only part of the process I still have to do manually is fitting the text onto the cards. So I'm looking for help finding a program that I can script to automate that one part of the process: Fitting text into boxes and spitting out an image file of the text-in-a-box.

Comment: P.S. I've tried using InDesign for this; suffice it to say that after multiple days of swatting InDesign bugs and working around limitations, I will not be listening to anyone who recommends InDesign. 

Yes, I know others have used InDesign to make game cards before. I've seen the tutorials. It works well as long as you're only doing one card at a time. 

At this point, I've got everything I want happening without InDesign, and it works better than I was ever able to make InDesign work, except for that one thing: Putting text in a box. I just need that one thing.

Comment: Should the program take a font and font size as input parameters (or settings)? Should it support fonts that are not fixed width?

Comment: I do need to be able to set those, yes. Your suggestion below sounds like it could totally fit the bill. I'm going to have to give it a try and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comfortable with HTML and command line, **pageres** could help.

You give pageres an HTML file and it returns you a screenshot of it.

So you could:

1. Wrap your input text inside an `<html><div>` of the size you want, with no margins
2. Run pageres on it
3. You may have to crop the resulting screenshot to the size you want (using imagemagick), as there may be white space at the right and bottom.

Open source (MIT license)
https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres-cli

Bonus: You can modify the HTML to use the font, font size, and colors you want.

I used pageres in a past project: https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/DoraStone/blob/master/dorastone.sh

Comment: This doesn't ACTUALLY do what I want: I still have to manually adjust the sizes for each text box individually, But it makes it easy enough to do that in live-server, seeing my changes on the fly as I tweak settings, and then when all the files pass I can run the command to collect everything with pageres -> imagemagick. It's a big enough step forward to get the big green check. Especially since someone came along and downvoted this question were it's likely to never another look.